# Playwright VS Code Windows install not creating files/folders

Tags: visual-studio-code, playwright, playwright-dotnet

When I follow the process here: https://playwright.dev/docs/getting-started-vscode#installation

It doesn't seem to do anything - even though VS Code is running with Elevated privileges.

I had previously followed the steps here and everything seemed to work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/playwright/#install-playwright-and-browsers

When I ran it in VS Code though it didn't seem to do anything - here is the output:

```
Create a package.json file

Usage:
npm init <package-spec> (same as `npx <package-spec>`)
npm init <@scope> (same as `npx <@scope>/create`)

Options:
[-y|--yes] [-f|--force] [--scope <@scope>]
[-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
[-ws|--workspaces] [--no-workspaces-update] [--include-workspace-root]

aliases: create, innit

Run "npm help init" for more info
```

In the video I was watching, installing Playwright through VS generated all sorts of files and folders.

https://youtu.be/Xz6lhEzgI5I?t=112

Answer (score 0):

Just tested [Playwright VSCode Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-playwright.playwright) in the empty folder with NodeJS 18 LTS - no errors.

VSCode extension basically performs `npm init playwright@latest` command with the parameters you select. So basically you can type it in the terminal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried the instructions as documented on another machine and it worked fine.

Also, running the command you posted in the folder in question from Windows Terminal with elevated privileges worked as well.

The command VS Code was running is:
```npm init playwright@latest --yes -- --quiet --browser=chromium --browser=firefox --browser=webkit --gha```

When I ran `npm init playwright@latest` in terminal it worked, but something in the parameters must be causing the problem. 